# UV protection for character LCD

Tags: temperature, lcd, uv

I am using 20X4 character LCD display.
Like these:  https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/big-size-20x4-line-white-color_62471561311.html?spm=a2700.pc_countrysearch.main07.78.2bafd2a7u344W2

The operating temperature rating is maximum 70 deg. cel. and I read that UV rays damage the LCD screen.
Are there any products or protective films that I can apply to protect from UV rays or direct sunlight?

Comment: Polycarbonate and many other common plastics are strongly UV absorbing.  If the LCD does not already have a plastic cover, you could add one.

Comment: Most things absorb UV. It's part of the reason UV anything is so expensive.

Comment: Those with a yellow / gold tint work best. Red and gray tints tend to darken the display too much.